# Dynamically return tick value, when hover over hyperlink tool tip

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am plotting a grouped bar chart with d3.js(v4). In this, I have made tool tip as hyperlink.

My requirement: When I hover over the tool tip, in the code, it should return the respective bar group x-axis tick value using which I'll set tool tip url to unique html files.

I am able to get xtick value using "data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOwqB.png).Week" likewise, however, it is not serving the purpose as I need this value to be mapped on run time with tool tip hovering behavior.

CSV file

```
Week,Total,Pass,Fail
w-32,4,4,0
w-33,2,1,1
w-34,2,0,2
w-37,2,1,1
w-38,1,1,0
w-39,1,1,0
```

Working Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
<style>

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: scale(.3);
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    70% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
  }
  @keyframes bounceIn {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: scale(.3);
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    70% {
      transform: scale(.9);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }

  .d3-tip.animate {
    animation: bounceIn 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: bounceIn 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  .d3-tip span {
    color: #ff00c7;
  }

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #FFE4C4;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  <!--box-sizing: border-box;-->
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #FFE4C4;
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

<!-- For setting overall graph dimensions:Start -->
</style>
<body>
<svg width="600" height="400"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
<script>
labels = ["Total", "Pass", "Fail"];
<!-- For setting overall graph dimensions:End -->

<!-- For setting graph margins:Start -->
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 33, right: 10,bottom: 150, left: 24},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var colour = ["#a9a9a9", "#66cc00", "#ff3333"]

<!-- For gaping between bar groups-->
var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.2);

<!-- For gaping between bars in groups-->
var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
    .padding(0.01);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#a9a9a9", "#66cc00", "#ff3333"]);

var timeout;

<!--Data read from csv and plot grouped bar chart-->
d3.csv("weekwise.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
   if (error) throw error;
        <!--console.log(data.length);-->
       var tool_tip = d3.tip()
       .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-8, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
           #Help needed here
           #This is where tool tip is getting set dynamically. However, all the bar are poiting to same html file.
           #I'll let each bar point to unique html file dynamically, if get the xtick value
           return '<a href= '+"wk"+31+"-"+d.key+"-"+d.value+".html" +' target="_parent">' + d.value + "</a>";
        }
    })

  svg.call(tool_tip)
  var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Week; }));
  <!--console.log(x0(d.Week));-->
  x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();
  g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Week) + ",0)"; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
      <!--// Tooltip stuff after this-->
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {
          <!--console.log(d);-->
          var context = this;
          var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
          args.push(this);
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            tool_tip.show.apply(context, args);
            }, 800);
        })
       <!--.on('mouseout', tool_tip.hide)-->
       .on('mouseout', function(d) {
          var context = this;
          var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
          args.push(this);
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            tool_tip.hide.apply(context, args);
          }, 2000);
        })

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));
    console.log(g);
 <!--Code for adding graph title-->
        g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
    .append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 1.5))
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "14px")
        .style("font-weight", "bold")
        <!--.style("text-decoration", "underline")-->
        .text("Build Statistics-v8.0.18");

<!--Code for defining and appending legend-->

var legend = g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("height", 100)
            .attr("width", 100)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(-5,' + (height + 50) + ')')
        .style("font", "12px sans-serif");

    legend.selectAll('rect')
        .data(labels)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
          .attr("x", function(d, i){
              var xPost = legendXPosition(labels, i, 6);
              return xPost;
          })
      .attr("y", -12)
          .attr("width", 12)
          .attr("height", 12)
          .style("fill", function(d, i) {
              var color = colour[i];
              return color;
          });

    legend.selectAll('text')
      .data(labels)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
          .attr("x", function(d, i){
              var xPost = legendXPositionText(labels, i, 22, 6);
              return xPost;
          })
      .attr("y", -1)
          .text(function(d) {
              return d;
          });


  function legendXPositionText(data, position, textOffset, avgFontWidth){
    return legendXPosition(data, position, avgFontWidth) + textOffset;
  }

  function legendXPosition(data, position, avgFontWidth){
    if(position == 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        var xPostiion = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < position; i++){
            xPostiion += (data[i].length * avgFontWidth + 40);
        }
        return xPostiion;
    }
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please have a look at the graph generated with the above code.

[image]

Comment: are you really sure this posted code works? my editor complains on a lot of locations. since when it is allowed to use HTML comment style in CSS and Javascript, have you matched all your braces correctly

Answer (score 1):

`d3-tip` doesn't allow much fiddling with data or nodes, so you are stuck with either having `d3-tip` return the data from the node that triggered it (where you would be missing the context of the parent node) or the parent node (where you would be without the information on what node was hovered over). The solution is either to add more data to each node (i.e. include the week in the data you bind to each node), or to dynamically pull in the week data when you hover over the node, like so:

```
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
      // if d.parent isn't defined, get the parent node of the current selection
      // and add that data to the current node
      if ( ! d.parent ) {
        d.parent = d3.select( this.parentNode ).datum();
      }
        tool_tip.show(d);
    }
```

If you try to manipulate the arguments to `tip.show()` in other ways, it'll throw up other errors as the arguments are used internally by `d3-tip`; they aren't passed straight through to the `tip.html()` function as you might have thought.

You would be better off including the week data in your bound data to circumvent this, though:

```
.data(function(d) {
  return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key], week: d.Week }; });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Ever considered adding the week number to your bound data?

```
.data(d => keys.map(key => ( {key: key, value: d[key], week:d.Week.slice(2)} )) )
```